# How do you automatically separate Camera photos from Safari photos?

Tags: iphone, photos, ios

I don't like how images downloaded from Safari and photos taken from Camera app are both dumped into the "Camera Roll" folder in Photos app. How do I configure my phone to automatically segregate the two types of images for better organization?

Comment: You can’t do that without a jailbreak and even so, the issue is too specific to likely have a fix.

Comment: I couldn't even manually separate the two types of images. I could only **copy** & paste to a new folder. I didn't see a way to **cut** & paste.

Comment: That’s what I said, you can’t do it without a jailbreak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered before, you cannot do that from the Camera app or Safari. But a workaround could be to use another camera-app ie "Camera+" which costs 1 or 2$.

Download Camera+, choose Menu, choose Autosave, choose Lightbox (Camera+'s own cameraroll). 
Then you save new pics to Lightbox - and you must export them from that of cos.